# How to exclude certain rows in a table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-bigquery

The code works fine, however, the URL I'm trying to fetch the table for seems to have headers repeated throughout the table, I'm not sure how to deal with this and remove those rows as I'm trying to get the data into BigQuery and there are certain characters which aren't allowed.

```
URL = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_games-august.html'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html')
driver.quit()
tables = soup.find_all('table',{"id":["schedule"]})

table = tables[0]
tab_data = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_all(["th","td"])]
                        for row in table.find_all("tr")]
json_string = ''
headers = [col.replace('.', '_').replace('/', '_').replace('%', 'pct').replace('3', '_3').replace('(', '_').replace(')', '_') for col in tab_data[1]]
for row in tab_data[2:]:
    json_string += json.dumps(dict(zip(headers, row))) + '\n'
with open('example.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_string)

    print(json_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `class` of the `tr` rows to None so that you don't get duplicate headers.

The following code creates a dataframe from the table

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

res = requests.get("https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2020_games-august.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("div", {"id":"div_schedule"}).find("table")
columns = [i.get_text() for i in table.find("thead").find_all('th')]

data = []

for tr in table.find('tbody').find_all('tr', class_=False):
    temp = [tr.find('th').get_text(strip=True)]
    temp.extend([i.get_text(strip=True) for i in tr.find_all("td")])
    data.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = columns)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                Date Start (ET)         Visitor/Neutral  PTS           Home/Neutral  PTS               Attend. Notes
0    Sat, Aug 1, 2020      1:00p              Miami Heat  125         Denver Nuggets  105  Box Score
1    Sat, Aug 1, 2020      3:30p               Utah Jazz   94  Oklahoma City Thunder  110  Box Score
2    Sat, Aug 1, 2020      6:00p    New Orleans Pelicans  103   Los Angeles Clippers  126  Box Score
3    Sat, Aug 1, 2020      7:00p      Philadelphia 76ers  121         Indiana Pacers  127  Box Score
4    Sat, Aug 1, 2020      8:30p      Los Angeles Lakers   92        Toronto Raptors  107  Box Score
..                ...        ...                     ...  ...                    ...  ...        ... ..     ...   ...
75  Thu, Aug 13, 2020             Portland Trail Blazers               Brooklyn Nets
76  Fri, Aug 14, 2020                 Philadelphia 76ers             Houston Rockets
77  Fri, Aug 14, 2020                         Miami Heat              Indiana Pacers
78  Fri, Aug 14, 2020              Oklahoma City Thunder        Los Angeles Clippers
79  Fri, Aug 14, 2020                     Denver Nuggets             Toronto Raptors

[80 rows x 10 columns]
```

In order to insert to bigquery, you can directly insert json to bigquery or a dataframe to bigquery using https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html

Comment: Can you show me how I can keep it in json like in my example, and remove the incompatible characters from the header?

Comment: Can you post the json structure you are looking for? I don't have selenium in my system

Comment: Basically just like this

`json_string = ''
headers = [col.replace('.', '_').replace('/', '_').replace('%', 'pct').replace('3', '_3').replace('(', '_').replace(')', '_') for col in tab_data[1]]
for row in tab_data[2:]:
    json_string += json.dumps(dict(zip(headers, row))) + '\n'
with open('example.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json_string)`

And I want to remove incompatible characters from header

Comment: @anthony Can you give an example json? Not the code, actual json

Comment: Well BigQuery only accepts new-line delimited JSON, which means one complete JSON object per line. I don't know how it should look though!